# Image Intervention draw image with text that has special characters

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using [ImageIntervention](http://image.intervention.io/) in Laravel 5.5 to generate an image.

When My text is `this is my text ♣`, the `♣` is rendered as a square box.
How can I make PHP render the correct character?

My code is like this:

```
$overlay = \Image::canvas(600, 500 );
            $overlay->rotate( 2);
            $overlay->text(
                'this is my text ♣',
                $overlay->getWidth() / 2,
                $overlay->getHeight() / 2,
                function ( $font ) use ( $textData ) {
                    /** @var \Intervention\Image\Gd\Font $font */
                    $font->file( resource_path( 'assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf' ) );
                    $font->size( 100 );
                    $font->angle( 2 );
                    $font->valign( 'center' );
                    $font->align( 'center' );
                } );
```

All the rest is working fine, it's just the rendering of the text which goes wrong and I have no idea why.

I've found out ImageIntervention is drawing the text here:
https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Font.php#L202

So it's using `imagettftext` to draw the text.
The Open Sans font does support the character so I don't think that is the problem.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at UTF-8 Miscellaneous Symbols

the one you're looking for is: *&9827;* or *&-clubs;* (without the -)

Comment: When I use these characters it still doesn't work. Where should I take a look to find out how to get it working?